# How to get current user id on Angular and Asp.Net Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, angular, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

Is there any way to get the current user on Angular using Angular + Asp.Net Boilerplate?

I know that I can get it on the API. But I want to send the object to the API with the current user id.

Comment: Can you show some code example what you have tried so far?

Comment: On angular I haven't tried anything because I couldn't find if exists an service there I can manage the current user.

Answer (score 3):

On ABP it's different

Call

```js
    import { ConfigStateService } from '@abp/ng.core';

    constructor(private configState: ConfigStateService)
```

And then

```js
      get currentUserId(): string {
        return this.configState.getDeep('currentUser.id');
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

On angular declare a object of UserLoginInfoDto class.
initialize the object value with this.appSession.user
import UserLoginInfoDto class.
For example:

```
userLogInInfo: UserLoginInfoDto;
```

and in Content or View Init

```
this.userLogInInfo = this.appSession.user;
```

Comment: Can't I just inject the AppSessionService on my component?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I found a service where I can get user info.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppSessionService {

    private _user: UserLoginInfoDto;
    private _tenant: TenantLoginInfoDto;
    private _application: ApplicationInfoDto;

    constructor(
        private _sessionService: SessionServiceProxy,
        private _abpMultiTenancyService: AbpMultiTenancyService) {
    }

    get application(): ApplicationInfoDto {
        return this._application;
    }

    get user(): UserLoginInfoDto {
        return this._user;
    }

    get userId(): number {
        return this.user ? this.user.id : null;
    }

    get tenant(): TenantLoginInfoDto {
        return this._tenant;
    }

    get tenantId(): number {
        return this.tenant ? this.tenant.id : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.  `_sessionService` and `_abpMultiTenancyService` are unused. `_user`, `_tenant` and `_application` are uninitialized.